# How can I implement this simple XAML Grid Layout in Android AXML?

Tags: android, xaml

I'm trying to get my head around Android layout in the context of a `ListView` and it seems pretty primitive (though it's entirely possible that I'm Doing It Wrong™), if I wanted to render something simple in a list view consisting of a Name and a Count, something like this:

[image]

I'd use this kind of XAML in WP8 / WPF / Silverlight:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Height="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Thing" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Count" />
</Grid>
```

However, that doesn't seem to be possible with Android Layout - I tried using `RelativeLayout` but it seems as if either one or the other would always be full size and the other would get eaten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Thing" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Count" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you could use a `LinearLayout` and set `weights`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="Thing" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Count" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or you could use a `GridView`, there is a [great example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) on developer.android.com.

Comment: Can you explain more about weights? Where can I read about that?

Comment: With weights you can set how much of the space the specified view should take in, in this example the "Thing" TextView takes up 4/5 of the space, while the other TextView occupies 1/5.  [You can read it up in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight)

Answer (score 1):

So here's the thing. Anything except a single string per record in grids require something special. This is not perfect code by any means, but it will help.

Let's start with your Base Layout.

Let's say this is in something called mainlist.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/itemList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So here you have a Relative with a ListView. Pretty basic right?

In your activity you will need some code like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
     setContentView(R.layout.mainlist);
     GetAndAssociateData();
}

public void GetAndAssociateData() {
      ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemList);
      final ArrayList<CountedItem> items;
      list.setAdapter(new CountedItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.countedItemRow, items, this));   
 }
```

Anything outside of that single string item requires not only an adapater, but a layout for each item.

CountedItemAdapter is the adapter in this case (it tells how how to populate the view).

countedItemRow is layout for each item.

/src/CountedItemAdapter.java

```
public CountedItemAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<CountedItem> objects,CountedItemActivity parentActivity) {
        super(context,  textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = objects;
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countedItemRow, null);
    }
    if (items != null){
        CountedItem item = items.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            TextView thing= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thing);
            if (thing!= null)
            {
                thing.setText(item.GetThingText());
            }
            TextView thingCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thingCount);
            if (thingCount != null)
            {
                thingCount .setText(item.GetThingCount());
            }

        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

/res/layout/countedItemRow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/countedItemRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/thing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/thingCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="150dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: While I appreciate the entire code sample, I've got everything but  laying out the tiles working :)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party. I'm not a huge fan of `GridView` with only 2 columns.  I recommend a ListView with weighted views in each list item layout. Also TableLayout may fit, but my example fails to scroll for some reason.  Click the button on the initial screen to get to the ListView example.

I quickly changed some test code I had laying around to fit your example - [**see here**](https://github.com/mike-marshall/androidlistexamples)